# Returning plots in repeated function calls without plotting in notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that returns plots **without saving images**. It uses the `pd.DataFrame.plot` method to plot the images and return them. I need to call this function repeatedly in a large number of iterations.

The problem is that I can't modify the function at all, therefore I need to be able to force the function to NOT display an image due to memory issues. Here is a reproducible toy example of the function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Can't modify this ->
def fig_gen():
    img = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,2)))
    fig = img.plot()
    return fig

#This is a BIG loop over 5k images
for i in range(4):
    fig_gen().get_figure().savefig('test.png')
```

---

I have gone through a bunch of approaches that were answered on Stack Overflow. I have tried using but the figure is still displaying -

```
plt.ioff()

## and

plt.close(fig)
```

I can't use `plt.savefig()` directly after plotting inside the function as I can't modify it.

Is there a way I can call the function repeatedly, but force matplotlib to not display the plot and only return the figure object, which I can then save using `Figure.savefig()` **outside** the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Jupyter, turn `inline` plotting off in `Jupyter` by using `%matplotlib qt` in a cell prior to plotting. This is a notebook wide setting, so only needs to happen once.

  - Turn `inline` plotting back on with `%matplotlib inline`, or going to <kbd>Kernel</kbd> and selecting<kbd>Restart Kernel and Clear All Outputs...</kbd>
- Adjust the `for-loop` as follows:

```py
for i in range(4):
    fig = fig_gen().get_figure()
    fig.savefig(f'test_{i}.png')
    fig.clf()
```